# java vector to arraylist

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

Is there any way to copy or convert a vector to arraylist in Java?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yup - just use the constructor which takes a collection as its parameter:

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
// (... Populate vector here...)
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(vector);
```

Note that it only does a shallow copy.

Comment: complexity is o(n) ?

Comment: @amdev: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, this helped.. I dint want to go with Iterator approach and all because of large chunk of data.. hence this helped.. better than iterating and populating the arrayList

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a class to do the same thing, but is more flexible as it will accept Objects accordingly.

```
public class ExteriorCastor {
    public static  ArrayList vectorToArrayList(Vector vector){
        if (vector == null){return null;}
        return new ArrayList<Object>(vector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i´m not sure if it is `length()` or `size()`.... but the idea is the next:

```
ArrayList<Object> a;

for(int i = 0;i < Vector.length() ; i++)

    a.add(Vector.elementAt(i); // Again... i´m not sure if this is elementAt() or get()

Vector.finalize();
```