# How do you change Vector to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, arraylist

I am developing an application in Java and since `Vector` is obsolete I am required to change this to using `ArrayList`.

This is the relevant code that needs to be changed to `ArrayList`:

This is the "House" Class.

```
public Vector<Vector> getItems() {
    Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<Vector>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _itemList.size(); i++) {
        Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
        row.add(_itemList.get(i).getDecription());
        row.add(String.valueOf(_itemList.get(i).getprice()));
        data.add(row);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is the GUI Class:

```
private void updateView() {

    //Gets Rows and Columns from the House.class
    Vector<Vector> rowData = _listener.getHouse().getItems();
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    columnNames.add("Product Name");
    columnNames.add("Product Price(€)");
    //Creates Shopping Cart and sets size + properties
    table1 = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(375, 325));
    table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    //Adds ScrollPane to the container and sets the component position to center
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table1);
    centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

I need to entirely stop the usage of VECTOR and use ArrayList instead. Is there a simple way out? Any ways on how to replace this?

Comment: What is the question here ? Just remove all the vectors with arraylist. Assumming you dont care about synchronising.

Comment: `ctrl + f` then `find/replace` :-)

Comment: I got your question but what have you tried ? First try it, if you get any error then there could be question. Be brave and just do it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do for the first one.

```
public List<List<String>> getItems() {
  List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < _itemList.size(); i++) {
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    row.add(_itemList.get(i).getDecription());
    row.add(String.valueOf(_itemList.get(i).getprice()));
    data.add(row);
  }
  return data;
}
```

The second is a little less trivial. You could start with something like this but I suspect using a `TableModel` would be a good step forward.

```
private void updateView() {
  //Gets Rows and Columns from the House.class
  List<List<String>> rowData = _listener.getHouse().getItems();
  List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  columnNames.add("Product Name");
  columnNames.add("Product Price(€)");
  //Creates Shopping Cart and sets size + properties
  // **** Will not work - Probably better to use a TableModel.
  table1 = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
  table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(375, 325));
  table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
  //Adds ScrollPane to the container and sets the component position to center
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table1);
  centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: See my comment on Stanley's answer.

Comment: @SayemAhmed - I agree - `ArrayList` changed to `List` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
// (... Populate vector here...)
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(vector);
```

This is from here [java vector to arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440082/java-vector-to-arraylist)

Comment: You should not declare your variables to be of type `ArrayList` unless you absolutely need to. From OP's post, I see he is using the methods that are declared in the `List` interface. So the type of `list` should be `List<String>`, rather than `ArrayList<String>`.