# Converting Vector to Arraylist

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, netbeans-7

Hello is there any way to convert vector into arraylist ? I want to make search options for my table but looks like it would be much easier with arraylist for me. I used search but surprising there was nothing about vectors.

```
public Vector<Vector<Object>> InfoForTheTable() {
    Scanner s = null;
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        if (line.startsWith("")) {
            String[] atoms = line.split("[#]");
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            row.add(atoms[0]);
            row.add(atoms[1]);
                    row.add(atoms[2]);
                    row.add(atoms[3]);
                    row.add(atoms[4]);
                    row.add(atoms[5]);
            data.add(row);
        }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    finally {
        if (s != null) {
        s.close();
        }
    }
    return data;
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue with current code ?

Comment: You have Vector of Vectors.. It's like it's more situable you tu use a  dictionary even than a `List of Lists`... and don't use <Object> use <String>

Comment: Problem solved, I used nachokk solution, trough other solutions are also good !

Comment: A side note: since Scanner implements AutoClosable consider to use try-with-resources

Comment: @user2121038 i edit solution xD

Comment: What kind of table are you using? A db table? JTable (Swing)?

Comment: Puce i am using Jtable(swing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to don't use that type of collections, first of all the main difference between ArrayList and Vector is that all vector operations are synchhronized. Second, you have a `Vector< Vector<Object> >` and you want this to be `ArrayList< ArrayList<Object> >` So in my opinion you should create your own class (bean class).

Example with at least Java 1.7:

```
public class myTableModel{
 private String somePropertyName1;
 .
 .
 .
 private String somePropertyNameN;

 public MyTableModel(String ... array){
    //assign values to instance attributes.
 }
  //getters and setters

}


//remember method names in java starts with lower-case
public List<MyTableModel> infoForTheTable() {
    List<MyTableModel> data = new ArrayList<>(); //diamond inference
    //use try-with-resources
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.getPath("info.txt"))){            
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = s.nextLine();
          if (line.startsWith("")) {
            String[] atoms = line.split("[#]");
            data.add(new MyTableModel(atoms[0],atoms[1],atoms[2],atoms[3],atoms[4],atoms[5]));
         }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        //handle exception or throw it up!
    }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Also: use Path instead of (legacy) Files.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
```

I recommend to use:

```
List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or even better: create a class MyInfo and assign the atoms values to its properties
Then use:

```
List<MyInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

So here is a more modern version of your code:

```
public List<Info> readInfoFromFile() {
    List<Info> infoList= new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.get("info.txt")){
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        if (line.startsWith("")) {
            String[] atoms = line.split("[#]");
            Info info = new Info();
            info.setA(atoms[0]);
            info.setB(atoms[1]);
            info.setC(atoms[2]);
            info.setD(atoms[3]);
            info.setE(atoms[4]);
            info.setG(atoms[5]);
            infoList.add(rowinfo); 
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    return data;
}
```

Replace the properties and their types as needed.

Comment: +1 yeah this is more correct i didn't read the code i'll edit

Answer (score 1):

just use the constructor which takes a collection as its parameter:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(row);
```

Note that it only does a shallow copy.

for more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440082/java-vector-to-arraylist?rq=1)

Comment: As shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440082/java-vector-to-arraylist?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ArrayList` has a constructor that takes a `Collection` (which `Vector` obviously is) to do so:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```